# Adding random to Wordpress Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an existing Wordpress page and use for a page to display post the pre_get_post funtions below. The Query filters in the website all posts for the custom post types "branchenbuch" and orders it DESC for a field profiltyp (People with a logo and people without a logo) This way all records are displayed in this sepcific order (people with a logo first). Now within these results (people with a logo) I also want the results to be displayed randomly, that not always the same post comes up first.

Currently this is in my funtions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_archive' );

function custom_post_type_archive( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'branchenbuch' ) ) {

  $query->set( 'meta_key', 'profiltyp' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
$query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to do this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question...but you can use `'orderby' => 'rand'` to randomly order query results in WordPress:

```
if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'branchenbuch' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'profiltyp' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
}
```

Read more about `orderby` options [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: yes, thank you. I can do this but than I have the problem that all results are shown randomly and I have specific posts that I need to show on top of the results despite the random order. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use the code

get all the selected posts which you need to be shown in the Top in an array let us say `$allowed_posts = array(121,233,144,900);`

```
$query->set( 'post__in', $allowed_posts );
$query->set( 'meta_key', 'profiltyp' );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
```